# Why Final variable doesn't require initialization in main method in java?

Tags: java, final

When I am just trying to do some program in **Java**.I try to use `final` variable,I know that `final` variable must be initialized at the time of declaration, but inside the main method it accepts the `final` variable with out initialization. I don't know what's the reason.Can any one tell me the reason.

Thank you

code:

```
class name
{
     final int b; //here shows error
     public static void main(String args[])
    {
        final int a; // here no error... why?
        System.out.println("hai");
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code so we can help you

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO check my update

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO i have one more doubt inside static method only access static variables.but here how it allows final

Comment: @KVK Look at the scope. Its local to that method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For **instance variable level**

- A final variable can be initialized only once.
- A final variable at class level must be initialized **before the end of the constructor**.

For **local (method) level**

- A final variable at method level can be initialized only once.
- It must be initialized **before it is used**

So basically if you don't use a local final variable you can also skip it's initialization.

If the variable is at instance level you have to initialize it in the definition or in the costructor body.

In your code you have an instance variable `final int b` that is never initialized so you have an error.

You have also a local variable `final int a` that is never used. So you haven't an error for that variable.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is provided in [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4).

> A variable can be declared final. A final variable may only be assigned to once. **It is a compile-time error if a final variable is assigned to unless it is definitely unassigned immediately prior to the assignment**.

[What is definitive assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html)

Now, in case of a local variable, it's scope is valid inside the block it's declared. And flow will be linear (from top to bottom). So the compiler can identify easily where the variable will be initialized at first.

But in case of a `field`, it's impossible to find which method will assign the variable first unless it's assignment in a `Constructor`.

So, you have to assign `final fields` **during declaration or in a Constructor**.

Answer (score 1):

Local variable has no default value right , bt we can declare like this

final int a;
there has no error 
but we cannot access it . when we try to access it , then error is occur .
But this case is not for class variable  .

So in your case when you access to print the value of a variable , error occur .
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

A instance variable if not marked final gets default value whereas a local variable do not get default value.

For instance variable "int b" to be final it has to be assigned at time of declaration or in constructor.

For local variable "int a" inside main method if it's not initialized do not get error.