# behaviour of local final variable in java

Tags: java, variables, local, final

i know this may get a down vote but this is something that is intriguing me

```
    public class finaltesting
{

    public static final String  v=900; //requires initialization


    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        final int c; // doesn't need initialization
        switch(get())
        {
            case 0:
            System.out.println("zero");
            break;
            case 1:
            System.out.println("one");
            break;
            case 2:
            System.out.println("two");
            break;
            case 3:
            System.out.println("three");
        }

    }
    static int get()
    {
        return (int)(Math.random()*4);

    }
}
```

but a final variable needs to be initialized right.. so why isn't there  any compile error with "final int c;"

does that mean final instance variables and final local variables are completely different

(* for people who think this possible duplicate of  'how a final variable works',it's not this is about local and instance final variable)

Comment: the compiler knows it's not used, whereas in case you declare it as static field it cannot.

Comment: @sinclair yes this is completely different question ..it's about local final variable and instance final variable.......

Comment: @zapl can you say something more

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602960/why-final-variable-doesnt-require-initialization-in-main-method-in-java. Same as this one. See if this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule goes like this:

> Each local variable (§14.4) and every blank final field (§4.12.4,
>   §8.3.1.2) must have a definitely assigned value when any access of its
>   value occurs.
>
> An access to its value consists of the simple name of the variable
>   (or, for a field, the simple name of the field qualified by this)
>   occurring anywhere in an expression except as the left-hand operand of
>   the simple assignment operator = (§15.26.1).
>
> For every access of a local variable or blank final field x, x must be
>   definitely assigned before the access, or a compile-time error occurs.

So the important thing is that when you access a variable, the final field (or any local variable) is already assigned. If you never access it, there's nothing to enforce. *(It's worth noting that the rule is the same for final and non-final local variables. The only difference is that a final local variable can't be assigned to **again**.)*

With a local variable the compiler can guarantee that it isn't accessed, therefore no assignment is necessary.

With a field this isn't always possible, so a final field is only considered to be definitely assigned if it's initialised in a constructor/static initialiser block (depending on whether the field is static or not).

All this is described in more detail in the rules on [Definite Assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html).

Comment: why can't compiler guarantee that with field..

Comment: How could he? If the field is public or protected, any class that ends up in the class path *at runtime* might access it, the compiler isn#t aware of those and can not reason about them. For *private* fields, this is ofc different, but they might have left fields out alltogether.

Comment: @Polygnome yaa that makes sense and again if an final  instance variable is allowed to get its initialization in method that would be totally flawed cause method can be called any number of times...

Comment: @viru That is not the reason. The compiler could determine wether or not it is possible for the method to be called multiple times iff it has global knowledge. But it doesn't, since jars can end up in the class path at runtime. Another reason is object construction - by forcing fields to be initialized in the constructor you can make sure that objects can not be partially constructed.

Answer (score 1):

Your local variable c does not give error as it's not a static field. Your instance variable is defined as static final and hence required initialization.

Comment: @kamat  this is not about static field ,compilation fails even when non-static final variable doesn't get initialization

Comment: and you can't  declare a local variable as static ...